How can I disable Activities that don't have a disable option?
Under Contacts, I want to remove "Print/Merge Documents" and "Meeting" from the "Report Activity" dropdown menu. But there is no "disable" button next to these Activities on the "Activity Type Options" page. Is there any way that I can disable them anyway?

You can do it in the database directly or using api explorer. For the option value set the filter column to 1, e.g.
UPDATE civicrm_option_value SET filter=1 WHERE name='Meeting' AND option_group_id=2;
(theoretically the option_group_id might not be 2, but it's always 2)
